# Why is XDebug producing corrupted files?

Tags: php, drupal, profiling, xdebug

I have XDebug enabled on my XAMPP installation. I've used XDebug + Wincachegrind to profile my code for some time. Recently XDebug started throwing some weird stuff into `cachegrind.out` files.

Examples of weird stuff:

```
fl=fl=php:internal
fn=php::ini_set
127 7
```

and

```
fl=C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal-5.7\includes\session.inc
fn=sess_close
0 3

=1 0 0
72 2991

fl=C:\xampp\htdocs\drupal-5.7\includes\session.inc
fn=sess_close
0 3

ession.inc
fn=sess_close
0 2
```

I'm writing Drupal modules, if it matters. What can be the cause of such behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't test for file writing concurrency. This happens if you have two requests at the same time that come into the same file. The trick would be to change the file format with settings as described [here](http://xdebug.org/docs/profiler#profiler_output_name).

Derick